# NullReferenceException when trying to populate an empty instance of a custom class with a struct

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct, nullreferenceexception

I have created a custom struct and a class. The structs are points in 3D Space:

```
public struct Point3D
{
    //fields
    private static Point3D center = new Point3D(0,0,0);

    //properties
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
    public static Point3D Center { get { return center; } }

    //constructors
    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) : this()
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("({0}; {1}; {2})", this.X, this.Y, this.Z); }
}
```

and the custom class is path which is supposed to store the points:

```
public class Path
{
    private List<Point3D> storedPoints = new List<Point3D>();

    public List<Point3D> StoredPoints { get; set; }

    public void AddPoint(Point3D point) { this.StoredPoints.Add(point); }

    public void DeletePointAt(int index) { this.StoredPoints.RemoveAt(index); }

    public void ClearPath() { this.StoredPoints.Clear(); }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in this.StoredPoints)
        {
            sb.Append(item);
            sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have not created a constructor for the path class as I will always want to have an instance with an empty list List\ in it. However, when I run the program, I get NullReferenceException. This is the code of the main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point3D point1 = new Point3D(-2, -4, -10);
        Point3D point2 = new Point3D(6, 7, 8);
        Path path1 = new Path();
        path1.AddPoint(point1);
        path1.AddPoint(point2);
        path1.AddPoint(new Point3D(2, 4, 6));
        path1.AddPoint(new Point3D(-9, 12, 6));
        Console.WriteLine(path1);
    }
```

I get the error when I try to add the first point. In the debugger I see that the Path object has the value null before adding the first point, but how do I overcome this problem without having to write a constructor, taking as a parameter at least one point, that is, create an empty path.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Just one sub-question. What if I remove the private field List<Point3D> storedPoints altogether and just leave the auto-property public List<Point3D> StoredPoints { get; set; }? Why is that not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StoredPoints` property is alone and not initialized.  Your intention is probably that it will get/set your private `storedPoints` field.  Modify the get/set functions for `StoredPoints` to get/set your private field and you'll solve your problem.

```
public List<Point3D> StoredPoints 
{ 
  get
  {
    return storedPoints;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you eliminate the `storedPoints` field, and still don't want a constructor, you can do the following:

```
public void AddPoint(Point3D point) 
{ 
  if (this.StoredPoints == null)
    this.StoredPoints = new List<Point3D>();
  this.StoredPoints.Add(point); 
}
```

This is called lazy initialization.  However, the above implementation is not thread-safe.  If you're guaranteed to be single-threaded, then it should be fine.  You may want to put similar initialization in other modifiers of `StoredPoints`.  You'll also need to check `StoredPoints` for null whenever accessing it directly from outside the class.

**Edit:**

> I have not created a constructor for the path class as I will always want to have an instance with an empty list List\ in it.

One has nothing to do with the other.  You can have a constructor and not initialize your list.

Something else to keep in mind:  does having a null `StoredPoints` property actually mean anything different than an empty `StoredPoints` property?  If not, then be safe and initialize `StoredPoints` to an empty list.

Comment: Regarding thread-safety, the very type `List<T>` is not thread-safe either, so even if he initialized it in a constructor, things would still break down in a multi-threaded scenario (where he should change to a collection from `System.Collections.Concurrent`).

Comment: Thank you both for the perfect explanation. The part I still don't get is why I have to initialize it,if I initialize it to an empty list, which by default has a value of null. In both cases it has a value of null, but in the second case it is explicitly initialized? But I guess this is something I need to further work on as I am a newbie.

Comment: By default, your property will have value `null`. If you initialize it using `new List<Point3D>()`, it will not be `null`, instead it will be an valid list that is empty.  Don't get confused between "no list" (which is null) and "empty list" (which is a list that exists, but is empty).

Answer (score 1):

You have two members `storedPoints` and `StoredPoints` that are not related!

You should write out the getter of `StoredPoints` explicitly and let it return `storedPoints`.

(Also, the struct you created is a mutable struct. That is considered dangerous by many.)

Comment: Because it's default value will be null.  You'll have to initialize it somewhere (usually in a constructor).

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Point3D> StoredPoints { get; set; }
```

When you are calling `AddPoints`, you are trying to access a property that has not been initialized. Before you use the `StoredPoints` property, you must do

```
StoredPoints = new List<Point3D>();
```